# Change colour of geom_ribbon based on continuous variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have monthly (long-term mean) climate data (precipitation and temperature) and want to make a combined bar (precipitation and number of rain days) and line graph (temperature) with left and right scale using ggplot2. So far it's working.

```
 lgj<-structure(list(Tmax = c(29.5, 30.5, 30.6, 30.6, 29.6, 29.1, 29.5, 
    31.5, 32.1, 31.9, 30.3, 29.8), Tmin = c(18.2, 17.7, 17.9, 16.1, 
    13, 10.2, 9.7, 11.4, 15, 17.2, 18.1, 18.4), Tav = c(23.2, 23.2, 
    23.2, 22.7, 20.7, 18.8, 18.9, 21.2, 23.2, 23.9, 23.4, 23.2), 
    Prec = c(244.5, 202.2, 196.2, 108.6, 38, 10.4, 5.1, 16.1, 
    57.3, 163.1, 185.2, 254.4), P_day = c(20L, 18L, 15L, 9L, 
    4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 11L, 18L, 22L), date = structure(c(11323, 
    11354, 11382, 11413, 11443, 11474, 11504, 11535, 11566, 11596, 
    11627, 11657), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Tmax", "Tmin", 
    "Tav", "Prec", "P_day", "date"), row.names = c("01.01.2001", 
    "01.02.2001", "01.03.2001", "01.04.2001", "01.05.2001", "01.06.2001", 
    "01.07.2001", "01.08.2001", "01.09.2001", "01.10.2001", "01.11.2001", 
    "01.12.2001"), class = "data.frame")
```

Further I would like to add a geom_ribbon displaying the min and max temperature, which is also working when using geom_ribbon (aes(..., group=1) without any colour and fill specification.

However it would be nice to give the ribbon a colour for each month, based on the average temperature of the respective month.
I found this answer to a similar question:
[Modifying geom_ribbon borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513103/modifying-geom-ribbon-borders)
and tried to implement it here:

```
ggplot(lgj,aes(x=date,y=Prec,fill=P_day,group=date))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax=lgj$Tmax, ymin=lgj$Tmin,fill=factor(lgj$Tav), colour=factor(lgj$Tav)), alpha=0.6) +
  geom_line(aes(x=lgj$date,y=lgj$Tav))
```

but it's not working in my case and I get the error:

> "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

If I try and remove the factor and add a group argument to geom_ribbon.

```
ggplot(lgj,aes(x=date,y=Prec,fill=P_day,group=date)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax=lgj$Tmax, ymin=lgj$Tmin, fill=lgj$Tav, colour=lgj$Tav,group=1), alpha=0.6) +
  geom_line(aes(x=lgj$date,y=lgj$Tav))
```

> "Error in f(...) : Aesthetics can not vary with a ribbon"

Any ideas how to make this run or a possible work-around?

Comment: What is `df`? You should make sure your code is reproducible, and remove the parts which are not required for the question

Comment: df was the dataframe. I edited the question. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: A geom ribbon requires at least two x values to be able to make a polygon. If you group it into months, you are only going to have a single x value, so all your polygons will appear as lines.